# What's pipenv equivalent for these pip options: --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/path/to/include/"

Tags: python, build, pipenv

Does anybody know the Pipenv equivalent for pip options:

```
--global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/path/to/include/"
```

I'm trying to use pipenv in context of a custom package build from source that works with pip.

I don't see a way to pass global options in pipenv manual. Thanks!